# Checking pfx file type with struts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

Is there any way to check the uploaded certificate is really a pfx certificate? I tried with the following code:

```
LazyValidatorForm lazyForm = (LazyValidatorForm) actionForm;
FormFile cerFile = (FormFile) lazyForm.get("cerFile");

if (!cerFile.getContentType().equals("application/x-pkcs12")) {
    /** return error code **/
}
```

However, most of the time, the content type is application/octet-stream, which is no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try loading the uploaded file into a [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html):

```
LazyValidatorForm lazyForm = (LazyValidatorForm) actionForm;
FormFile cerFile = (FormFile) lazyForm.get("cerFile");

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(cerFile.getInputStream(), null);
```

Even if the .pfx contains a password protected private key, the .pfx should still be loaded (it's basically useless without the password but it should load).

If you get no exception and the `keyStore.size()` equals 1 after the load, then it must be a .pfx file.